# TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable, when checking length of a nested-list

Tags: python, typeerror, nested-lists

I have been getting a `TypeError` when running the code below. I don't understand why it won't take the length of `listLicencePlates`, when its a `list`? I tried to figure out for about an hour now and can't seem to see the mistake. Maybe someone can point out why this happens and how to fix it?

When I run this code:

```
for x in range[len(listLicencePlates)]:
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Here's my full code:

```
def match_list(witnessedLicensePlate, listLicencePlates):
    matchPlates = len(listLicencePlates)*[len((witnessedLicensePlate))*[""]]
    for x in range[len(listLicencePlates)]:
        y = 0
        for y in range(len(witnessedLicensePlate)):
            if witnessedLicensePlate[y] != listLicencePlates[x][y] and witnessedLicensePlate[y] != "?":
                    y = len(witnessedLicensePlate)
            else:
                matchPlates[x][y] = listLicencePlates[x][y]
    return matchPlates


print(match_list("VF???55",["VX33322","VF12355","VF77455","DA?????","VF10055"]))
```

Comment: `range(`, not `range[`.

Comment: But anyway, iterating over range(len(something)) is almost always the wrong thing to do in Python.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know exactly what you want to achieve but I ran the same code and it works fine. Although I must say, I changed range[ to range( as corrected above.

Answer (score 0):

### Fixing the TypeError:

The interpreter is telling you *exactly* where and why you're getting the issue. Here's your [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
>>> range[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

You can't use square brackets, or subscripts (i.e. `[]`) on the built-in `range`. Rather, use parenthesis (`()`):

```
>>> range(1)
range(0, 1)
```

So change this line:

```
for x in range[len(listLicencePlates)] # bad news, range[...]
```

to be

```
for x in range(len(listLicencePlates)) # Better, range(...)
```

and you'll get past the `TypeError`.

### Fixing the core issue:

I am guessing, however, that the output you get from this fix *isn't* what you want. This is the output:

```
[['V', 'F', '1', '0', '0', '5', '5'], ['V', 'F', '1', '0', '0', '5', '5'], ['V', 'F', '1', '0', '0', '5', '5'], ['V', 'F', '1', '0', '0', '5', '5'], ['V', 'F', '1', '0', '0', '5', '5']]
```

Which doesn't look useful.

What I think you *probably* want is an array of `bools`, where each `bool` describes whether or not the plate matched character by character, and the `"?"` represents a wildcard character.

Let's try a more Pythonic and less C-style approach to the problem with some extraordinarily verbose comments:

```
def match_list2(witnessed_plate, license_plates):
    matching_plates = []
    # just loop through the items, no need for range/indices                                                                                                                                                
    for possible_match in license_plates:
        # If they match, create 2-elt list with           
        # the plate as first elt and whether or not it matches as second    
        # Worry about do_plates_match later. Just get the high level logic
        # down pat and sound first.                                                                               
        matching_plates.append([possible_match,
                                do_plates_match(possible_match, witnessed_plate)])
    return matching_plates

def do_plates_match(plate1, plate2): # Define if they match (the time to worry is upon us)                                                                                                                                                
    # Loop through characters from plate1 and plate2 simultaneously                                                                                                                                     
    for first_char, second_char in zip(plate1, plate2):
        if first_char == "?" or second_char == "?":
            # If we get a question mark, go to the next character                                                                                                                                           
            continue
        elif first_char != second_char:
            # If they don't match at *some* character,
            # we know they can't match regardless of what's next, so return False                                                                                                            
            return False
    # Only way to get here is we must have matched for all characters, return True.                                                                                                                                                    
    return True
```

and for those who find the comments distracting and would rather just read the code straight away:

```
def match_list2(witnessed_plate, license_plates):
    matching_plates = []                                                                                                                                              
    for possible_match in license_plates:                                                                            
        matching_plates.append([possible_match, do_plates_match(possible_match, witnessed_plate)])
    return matching_plates

def do_plates_match(plate1, plate2):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    for first_char, second_char in zip(plate1, plate2):
        if first_char == "?" or second_char == "?": continue                                                                                                                                          
        elif first_char != second_char: return False                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    return True
```

Now calling:

```
plate = "VF???55"
print("Plate: ", plate)
print(match_list2(plate,["VX33322","VF12355","VF77455","DA?????","VF10055"]))
```

outputs:

```
Plate:  VF???55
[['VX33322', False], ['VF12355', True], ['VF77455', True], ['DA?????', False], ['VF10055', True]]
```

clearly showing which plates match, and which don't.

HTH.